# Scala - how to make generic decoder in circe?

Tags: scala, refactoring, scala-cats, circe, jsondecoder

I have two similar functions which have different return types:

```
override def getUsers(uri: Uri): F[Either[CodecException, List[User]]] =
    for {
      response <- retrieveDataFromClient(uri)
      result <- Sync[F].delay(response)
    } yield result

  override def getAnimals(uri: Uri): F[Either[CodecException, List[Animal]]] =
    for {
      response <- retrieveDataFromClient(uri)
      result <- Sync[F].delay(response)
    } yield result
```

And I have implicit `circe` decoders for them:

```
 implicit def decodeUser(response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[User]] = Decoder[List[User]].decode(response.entity)

 implicit def decodeAnimal(response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[Animal]] = Decoder[List[Animal]].decode(response.entity)
```

Now I have refactored first two methods into generic one:

```
 override def getData[A](uri: Uri): F[Either[CodecException, List[A]]] =
    for {
      response <- retrieveDataFromClient(uri)
      result <- Sync[F].delay(response)
    } yield result
```

And created generic `circe` decoder:

```
 implicit def decodeGeneric[A](response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[A]] = Decoder[List[A]].decode(response.entity)
```

But I got compilation error:

```
Could not find an instance of Decoder for List[A]
implicit def decodeGeneric[A](response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[A]] = Decoder[List[A]].decode(response.entity)


not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit instance: hammock.Decoder[List[A]])hammock.Decoder[List[A]] in object Decoder.
Unspecified value parameter instance.
implicit def decodeGeneric[A](response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[A]] = Decoder[List[A]].decode(response.entity)
```

Method `retrieveDataFromClient` return `F[HttpResponse]` from http client `Hammock` and response is implicit parsed into type `User` and `Animal` (via above decoders and works fine), but now I want to have it generic to remove boilerplate.
Is it possible to refactor this code in this way and create generic decoder?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using auto derivation?

Comment: No, is it possible to resolve it with derivation?

Comment: Remove all of your decoders, just import `import io.circe.generic.auto._` at the place where you need the object to be decoded. You shouldn't need to write any code for this.

Comment: Ok, but it did not solve a problem. Still get: `type mismatch;
 found   : hammock.HttpResponse
 required: Either[hammock.CodecException,List[A]]
    } yield result`

Comment: Read the docs for hammock circe: http://pepegar.com/hammock/marshalling.html

Comment: I read them. I also use Hammock decoder in my code, as I showed it above. I need to create generic code instead of concrete as it is right now

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a generic decoder for every `A`, constrain your `A` in your `decodeGeneric` method to those that can be decoded. Circe auto should give you a decoder for your `User` and `Animal` classes.

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._

implicit def decodeGeneric[A](response: HttpResponse)(implicit decoder: Decoder[A]): Either[CodecException, List[A]] = 
    Decoder[List[A]].decode(response.entity)
```

Comment: Ok, understand. So how I shuold refactor this two similar methids `getUsers` and `getAnimals` to remove boilderplate?

Comment: Your getData method looks ok, does it not work if you place this `decodeGeneric` and circe auto in scope?

Comment: No, it doesnt. I go another error: `ambiguous implicit values:
 both value decodeUser in object parsers of type => io.circe.Decoder[domain.User]
 and value decodeAnimal in object parsers of type => io.circe.Decoder[domain.Animal]
 match expected type io.circe.Decoder[A]
      result <- Sync[F].delay(response)`

Comment: Yes, I removed them now and back to old error from above post: `type mismatch; found : hammock.HttpResponse required: Either[hammock.CodecException,List[A]] } yield result`

Comment: Do you have the hammock implicit in scope? `import hammock.circe.implicits._`

Comment: Oh, also you need to pass the type to your getData method, like so: `getData[Animal]`. This will remove the ambiguous reference

Comment: yes, I call this by `getData[User]` or `getData[Animal]` and same error

Comment: Replacing the hammock `HttpResponse` type with `String`, I get: `decodeGeneric[Animal]("""[{"kind": "Tiger"}]""")` returns `Right(List(Animal(Tiger)))`. I'm not sure how hammock marshaling works, but normal circe works here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method signature by introducing a [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)

```
 implicit def decodeGeneric[A: Decoder](response: HttpResponse): Either[CodecException, List[A]] = Decoder[List[A]].decode(response.entity)
```

Comment: It did not help